# Laravel Array Conversion of array enclose to bracker

Tags: php, arrays

how can i convert this array

```
array:1 [
          0 => "Cambodia, Japan" 
]
```

into like this   **$destinations = ['Cambodia','Japan'];**

Comment: what have you tried? This is a very basic PHP functionality. Just a case of `explode()` the string to an array.

Comment: i try to explode it it show only    "Cambodia, Japan"   it doesnt have  'Cambodia','Japan'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the PHP `explode()` function.

```
$array = [ "Cambodia, Japan" ];
$destinations = explode(', ', $array[0]);
```

Comment: i want my array to be like this $destinations = ['Cambodia','Japan']; not the reverse one

Comment: that is exactly what this code will do